# unknown action in controller - routes.rb issue? weird results by changing from singular to plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, destroy

I'm getting a strange reaction to my 'destroy' method. I get this error when trying to destroy a project:

```
Unknown action
The action '5' could not be found for ProjectsController
```

I figured out when when I change my routes.rb file from `resources :projects` (plural) to `resources :project` (singular), the destroy action works as it should (and returns to the index) but then my show method works but update and new methods throw `undefined method`projects_path'` errors.  Why is this happening??

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    @projects = Project.sorted
    end

    def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new 
    @project = Project.new
    @project_count = Project.count + 1
    end

  def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    # Save the object
    if @project.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
      flash[:notice] = "Project created successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      @project_count = Project.count + 1
      render('new')
    end
  end

 def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project_count = Project.count
  end

  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Project updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @project.id)
    else
      @project_count = Project.count
      render('edit')
    end
  end

 def delete
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    project = Project.find(params[:id])
    project.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Project '#{project.name}' destroyed successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

private

    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:name, :financing, :visible, :position)
    end
end
```

routes.rb file:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

      root :to => 'projects#index'
      resources :projects

      match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
      # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
      # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

      # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
      # root 'welcome#index'

      # Example of regular route:
      #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

      # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
      #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

      # Exampl

e resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Delete.html.erb page:

```
<% @page_title = "Delete Project" %>

<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="project destroy">
  <h2>Delete Projects</h2>

  <%= form_for(:project, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @project.id}) do |f| %>

    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this project?</p>

    <p class="reference-name"><%= @project.name %></p>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Delete Project") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

[UPDATE]
Another interesting update. I messed around with destroy and changed the controller to:

```
 def delete
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.destroy

  end

  def destroy
    project = Project.find(params[:id])
    project.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Project '#{project.name}' destroyed successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end
```

I did this to see if it was an issue with the destroy method. It does destroy the project, and still returns the delete page which causes the same error, but it does destroy it.

Comment: first thing first (this may have nothing to do with the error message): in your destroy action, it should be `@project` instead of `project`. what's the purpose of `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]`. `match` does not work with `rails 4`

Comment: why do you have a `Delete.html.erb page:`? the practice is to delete an object from the `show` page.

Comment: My understanding to use project instead of @project is because I don't need to store it as a variable anymore but need to instantiate it so that it can be referenced one more time in the flash notice (i.e. "xxx project has been destroyed"). The purpose of the match statment is to route files based on the controller/action/id when issuing a get or post command -- based on a Lynda course I took. I want to have a confirmation page or pop-up so that I can warn the user (because my program will eventually have a lot of data in each project, with probably 20+ hours of work).

Answer (score 0):

Though you are doing a couple of unconventional stuff like having `delete.html.erb` (objects are deleted from the show view page), I'm going to address your direct question.

you said:

"when I change my routes.rb file from resources :projects (plural) to resources :project (singular), the destroy action works as it should (and returns to the index) but then my show method works but update and new methods throw undefined method projects_path'` errors. Why is this happening??"

you have understand every time you change your routes, you have to modify the helper paths in your views.

example: when you had `resources :projects`, you helper methods were (run rake db:migrate)

```
projects_path        GET     /projects(.:format)          projects#index
                     POST    /projects(.:format)          projects#create
new_project_path     GET     /projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
edit_project_path    GET     /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
project_path         GET     /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
                     PATCH   /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
                     PUT     /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
                     DELETE  /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
```

So at this point, `projects_path` was working because as you can see above, `projects_path` is there.

when you changed your routes to `resources :project`(singular), your helper paths change as well. run `rake db:migrate` to see them:

```
project_index_path   GET     /project(.:format)  project#index
                     POST    /project(.:format)  project#create
                     GET     /project/new(.:format)  project#new
                     GET     /project/:id/edit(.:format)     project#edit
                     GET     /project/:id(.:format)  project#show
                     PATCH   /project/:id(.:format)  project#update
                     PUT     /project/:id(.:format)  project#update
                     DELETE  /project/:id(.:format)  project#destroy
```

As you can see the helper path that maps to `project#index` is `project_index_path`.

So I'm guessing in your `edit.html.erb` (or somewhere else) you have the old code: `projects_path` and so you are getting `undefined method projects_path` because the helper no longer exist. The correct helper method in this case, is `project_index_path`.

Comment: I'm actually using simple_form_for which I think references the same routes through the controller as submitting the destroy command --? here is the code

<div class="project edit">
 <h2>Update Project</h2>

 <%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :financing, :label => "funding type: ", :collection => Project::FINANCING, :selected => "cash" %>
 <%= f.input :name, label: "project name: " %>
 <%= f.input :position, label: "position:  (importance)"  %>
 <%= f.input :visible, label: "visible"  %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
</div>

Comment: I'm not sure what that code is about. and I don't see `projects_path` code in there. the code that's giving you the error message.

Comment: i'm sorry, that is the edit form for reference. I'm using simple_form_for so it automatically follows the routes.rb path i believe...